Is Rudin's Dowker space hereditarily normal?
Its known that there exist Dowker spaces which are $T_5$, see e.g. this article.
However, I couldn't find anywhere if Rudin's Dowker space is $T_5$, and as of today, this property is not known in pi-base. Other normality-type properties are known e.g. Rudin's space is finitely-fully normal.
That is, Rudin's Dowker space is defined as the space $$X = \{f\in \prod_{n=1}^\infty (\omega_n+1) : \exists_i \forall_n \omega_0 < \text{cf}(f(n)) < \omega_i\},$$ originally defined by Rudin as an example of a normal space $X$ such that $X\times [0, 1]$ is not normal.
Is Rudin's space hereditarily normal?

No, Rudin's Dowker space is not hereditarily normal. To see this, note that $X$ has the space $$Y = \{(\alpha, \beta)\in \omega_2\times (\omega_2+1) : \text{cf}(\alpha), \text{cf}(\beta) > \omega_0\}$$ as a subspace. Indeed, the subset of those $f\in X$ for which $f(n) = \omega_1$ if $n\neq 2, 3$ and $f(2) < \omega_2, f(3)\leq \omega_2+1$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. I'll show that $Y$ is not normal. My proof is based on a proof of the classic result that the product $\omega_1\times (\omega_1+1)$ is not normal (see Handbook of set-theoretic topology, chapter 18, example 2.2).
Consider $K_1 = \{(\alpha, \beta)\in Y: \alpha = \beta\}$ and $K_2 = \{(\alpha, \beta)\in Y : \beta = \omega_2\}$. Its not hard to see that $K_1, K_2$ are disjoint closed subsets of $Y$. Suppose that we can find disjoint open sets $U_1, U_2$ with $K_i\subseteq U_i$. For each $\alpha < \omega_2$ with $\text{cf}(\alpha) > \omega_0$ find $f(\alpha) < \alpha$ such that $(f(\alpha), \alpha]^2\cap Y\subseteq U_0$. Since the set $S = \{\alpha < \omega_2 : \text{cf}(\alpha) > \omega_0\}$ is stationary in $\omega_2$, by pressing down lemma there exists a stationary set $S_1\subseteq S$ in $\omega_2$ such that $f\restriction_{S_1}$ is constant, say $f(\alpha) = \alpha_0$ for all $\alpha\in S_1$.
Consider the point $x = (\alpha_0+\omega_1, \omega_2)\in Y$. For any neighbourhood $V = (\{\alpha_0+\omega_1\}\times (\beta, \omega_2])\cap Y$ of $x$ where $\beta < \omega_2$, since $S_1\subseteq \omega_2$ is unbounded there exists $\alpha\in S_1$ and $\beta_0< \omega_2$, $\text{cf}(\beta_0) = \omega_1$, such that $\beta < \beta_0 \leq\alpha$, and so $U_0\cap V\supseteq (\alpha_0, \alpha]^2 \cap V\ni (\alpha_0+\omega_1, \beta_0)$
. It follows that $x\in \overline{U_0}\cap K_1$, but this is impossible. The contradiction proves that $Y$ is not normal, and so $X$ is not $T_5$.
